# How to have nested routerLink in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular7

I have a project in angular 7

I have router links with `<a>` tag, and I have nested `<a>` tags that both have `routerLink` property,

the issue I am facing is , the inner `<a>` route doesn't work

```
<a [routerLink]="[ './comp1']">
    Comp1
    <a [routerLink]="['./comp2']">
        Navigate to comp2 (Nested)
    </a>
</a>
```

this is working if I separate it

```
<div>
    <a [routerLink]="['./comp2']">
        Navigate to comp2 (Not Nested)
    </a>
</div>
```

Also I tried the below code and still same

```
<a [routerLink]="[ './comp1']">
    Comp1
    <a [routerLink]="['./comp2']" (click)="$event.preventDefault()>
        Navigate to comp2 (Nested)
    </a>
</a>
```

changing `a` tags to span also doesn't solve the issue

```
<span [routerLink]="[ './comp1']" >
    Comp1
    <span [routerLink]="['./comp2']" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
        Navigate to comp2 (Nested)
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-router for it

Comment: Interesting. I am guessing that nesting these will cause them to overlay, so the outer (A) overlays B. Not sure however

Comment: I am wondering if this is an event propagation issue where it is triggering the redirection to `comp2` and then immediately triggering the redirection to `comp1`? When this compiles it isn't using native browser navigation, it's all wrapped up in events.

Comment: but why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Roj Maybe something like clicking the outer will take you to a collection, clicking the inner will take you to the specific one ?

Comment: @Zze but you don't need nested links for that. And besides you can't have nested links work in the first place. If it's a visual think then just make a `ul` and style accordingly, no?

Comment: @Roj this is going to be in menu, which outer one direct you to list and inner one direct you to add (which is a + sign button), because of styling and using a third party library if I want to move it outside it will be a big refactor, so I was thinking this should work out of the box

Comment: @Zze Seems so, is there any way top prevent it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your stackblitz add the following function to your component class. It receives the event as parameter and calls the `stopPropagation` function on it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  stop(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

In your template do

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a routerLink="/comp1">
  Comp1
  <a routerLink="/comp2" (click)="stop($event)">
    Navigate to comp2 (Nested)
  </a>
</a>
```

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-router-j5eg95) fork.

Comment: Thanks, I was so close to solution ;)
I tried `(click)="$event.preventDefault()"` and wasn't working