# Angular router link active nested menu

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to make a nested menu with angular routes.

What I need is to apply class to a nested route if it's active and apply class to a parent component if its child is active.

How do I achieve this? For now I'm doing recursive menu building for ease of use when I need multilevel nesting.

component.html

```
<a (click)="toggleActive()" [class.active]="isActive" [routerLink]="menuItem.link" *ngIf="menuItem.link; else noLink">
  <i *ngIf="menuItem.faClass" class="fa fa-{{menuItem.faClass}}"></i>
  {{menuItem.name}} <span *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
</a>

<ng-container *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0">
  <ul class="nav child_menu" [class.active]="isActive" routerLinkActive="active"
      *ngFor="let item of menuItem.children">
    <li menu-item [menuItem]="item" (checkActive)="updateActiveState()"></li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noLink>
  <a (click)="toggleActive()" [class.active]="isActive">
    <i *ngIf="menuItem.faClass" class="fa fa-{{menuItem.faClass}}"></i>
    {{menuItem.name}} <span *ngIf="menuItem.children && menuItem.children.length > 0" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '[menu-item]',
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-item.component.scss'],
  host: {
    '[class.active]': 'hostActive && isActive',
    '[class.active-sm]': 'hostActiveSm && isActive'
  }
})
export class MenuItemComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  public menuSize;
  public isActive = false;

  @Input() menuItem: MenuItem;
  @Output() checkActive: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @ViewChild(MenuItemComponent) menuComponent: MenuItemComponent;

  private hostActive = true;
  private hostActiveSm = false;

  @HostBinding('class') hostClass = this.hostActive && this.isActive ? 'active' : this.hostActiveSm && this.isActive ? 'active-sm' : '';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private uss: UiStateService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uss.menuSubject.subscribe(msg => {
      this.menuSize = msg;
      if (this.menuSize === MenuSizes.sm) {
        this.hostActive = false;
        this.hostActiveSm = true;
      } else {
        this.hostActive = true;
        this.hostActiveSm = false;
      }
      this.updateActiveState();
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe((e: Event) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.updateActiveState();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateActiveState();
  }

  public toggleActive(): void {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    // if (this.menuComponent) {
    //   this.menuComponent.isActive = true;
    // }
  }

  private updateActiveState(): void {
    // reset previous state
    this.isActive = false;
    if (this.menuComponent) {
      this.menuComponent.isActive = false;
    }

    // Check state of item with no els
    const url = this.router.url;
    console.log('URL', url, 'Menu link', this.menuItem.link);
    console.log(url.match('/' + this.menuItem.link + '$/'));
    if (this.menuItem && this.menuItem.link && url.match('/' + this.menuItem.link + '$/')) {
      this.isActive = true;
      this.checkActive.emit();
    }

    if (this.menuComponent) {
      console.log('Menu component');
      console.log(this.menuComponent, this.menuComponent.menuItem.link);
      this.isActive = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way of knowing from a component whether its route is active? The trick is that I'm using `[routerLink]` and not a `routerLink` so that I can pass `.` as a link to the root page.

## Update

The best I could recreate [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwwrse)
Try to visit "Dasboard". It should add an "active" class to parent `li`. If you add it yourself you would see the applied class on it's element and a colored bar on the right.

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz example?

Comment: It's too complicated cause it requires almost full aplication to recreate

Comment: @yurzui updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to workaround it. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwwrse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu-item%2Fmenu-item.component.html)

Mainly it's achieved by using `setTimeOut` without a time in `navigateEnd` event so that I can check the state of `isActive` and get the value(if there is no setTimeout the value is gotten "from the past" meaning it's not updated when it's taken). It works in a bit tricky way but it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try access ActivatedRoute in any component

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';    

 constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url)  // array of states
    console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path) 
 }
```

Hope that will help!

Comment: Please reread the end of my question. I may pass `.` since I'm using [routerLink] and I don't want to match this case manually since it could change over time.

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong but you said very clear 'Is there a way of knowing from a component whether its route is active?'. Im answering that. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtqzed)

All of this functionality is built inside Angular's router module natively. This is the whole idea behind child routes. If a route is truly a parent component, it should be a parent in the routing. By doing this, you can simply check if the parent route is active instead of any of the routes arbitrarily assigned in the app component.

Additionally, this has the huge benefit of allowing dashboard to simply route to `['../sibling']`

In my child routes specifically /home/home.routes, you will see a commented line that would enable the dashboard to automatically load if that was the desired behaviour.

You are already using `routerLinkActive`, in your dynamic menu-item, but to have the most straightforward approach, it should be on the item bound to the routerLink as outlined [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links).

The biggest issue you will likely encounter is that nested routerLink elements do not play nicely in the DOM as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147005/how-to-have-nested-routerlink-in-angular) so you need to stop propagation.

app-component.html

```
<ul app-menu-item 
  class="nav side-menu"
  [menu]="menu">
</ul>
```

menu-item.html:

```
<li
  *ngFor="let item of menu"
  [routerLink]="item.link"
  routerLinkActive="active"
  (click)="stop($event)">

    {{item.name}}

    <ul app-menu-item
      *ngIf="item.children"
      class="nav side-menu"
      [menu]="item.children">
    </ul>
</li>
```

I will add, though it doesn't answer the title in your question, that this problem is most easily solved by using parent routes, and then setting up menu-item.html as follows:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menu">
  <a [routerLink]="item.link" routerLinkActive="active">
    {{item.name}}
  </a>
  <ul class="nav side-menu"
  *ngIf="item.children"
  app-menu-item [menu]="item.children">
  </ul>
</li>
```

and then using a sibling selector in your scss to show or hide the menu.

Comment: The idea is that "Home" that contains dashboard should have class active. In real application it's a kinda accordion and I need to expand an item when it's descendants are active. (by applying the class to the item).

Comment: In my example, the styling was off, but it does have the active class. Take a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1bl3u). It may be more clear.

Comment: you've done it in a wrong way. I've told about recursion meanwhile in your example it's absent. That means that you've got only 2 levels of menu and if I pass with `dashboard` children it won't render them.

Comment: Updated answer and stackblitz given your feedback.

Comment: nice work but still not the same :) Your implementation now lacks a such thing as linkless item, because it's a strange thing when a parent item has link, meanwhile it's just a grouping item. Since, we cannot do a conditional route link (which exists only if a value present [routerLink]="" refers to a home page) we do have a problem with propagating this routerActive state to a parent that doesn't have a link itself.

Comment: Why is a linkless item required? I saw it as part of your solution, but it seemed like you used it because you didn't have your routes set up in a hierarchy. The parent should always have a link. I don't understand why you would ever need a linkless item. Your app can optionally define a `{path: '', redirectTo: 'whatever', pathMatch:'full'}` in all the *.routes.ts files to define default behaviour so that '/' redirects to the desired active route. But yes, if a parent app is only a grouping item, it's html would simply be a `router-outlet` with such a redirect defined in the routes.

Comment: Because it's just a grouping item. It's like in MS Word you navigate over tabs and then you choose the action. The tab itself isn't an action but a grouping element. Thus it's a need to have a linkless item because it should NOT be a link. It's just a semantic wrapper for the child links. Just a grouping item. It's like a bootstrap's dropdown but made in accordion way (it expands when clicked or child is active).

Comment: But activating the tab shows that tab's component! It's just a component full of more actions. It's hard without more details for why this doesn't solve your issue, but at this point, I'm no longer answering your question, just trying to solve your problem. But take a look at how they do this in https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview. To really solve your problem, I think the right approach is to use sibling components which completely circumvents this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is way simpler to achieve by assigning template variable to the child and checking it on the parent like this -

```
<li [ngClass]="{ 'is-expanded': rla.isActive }">
  <!-- is-expanded or active or whatever class in your template makes it active. -->
  <a>Parent Item</a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/child" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive"
        >Child</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: If you have multiple child links? Do you have #rla1="..." and #rla2="..." with the [ngClass] condition `rla1.isActive || rla2.isActive` - or am I missing something?