# JS spy on object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've got an Angular app and I need to set some sort of spy on `routerLinkActive` object so that I could make some `Subject` and emit a value to notify element about changes? Is there a way to do so? I've seen the JS Proxy but it doesn't seem to work like listeners for DOM events do when you don't have to use that listener to interact with a spied target.

That isn't about unit tests but about work of app that should know where link becomes active/inactive and react on it (`routerLinkActive` as is is not enough for my purposes).

Comment: Can you use the router events to listen for changes, and check the routerLinkActive to see if it's active?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because I pass link to the `[routerLink]` from an object which may contain `.` for target of a current level root, thus I cannot use some kind of regexp matchers to track when I'm on home page when it's set to `.` or `/`.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about what it is you're trying to achieve? Maybe an example in Stackblitz?

Comment: That's coming from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299952/angular-router-link-active-nested-menu/53418795?noredirect=1#comment93774784_53418795

Comment: The problem is that `routerLinkActive` successfully works with any kind of routes, but when I pass it to the component there is no observable or event when `isActive` changes. That's why I need a kinda spy on that object

Comment: Well, it's only going to change when the route changes, which is why I was suggesting listening to router changes, and for each change you can use the `isActive` property of the `routerLinkActive`

Comment: The property isn't changed right after navigation end. this is a problem