# Angular navigation issue

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

When I click the **whole card** it should navigate to the project detail component and then when I click the **BID RECEIVED button** it should navigate to the bids component but it navigates to project detail page

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let data of projectdata">
   <div class="card-body" routerLink="/projectdetail/{{data._id}}">
      <div class="bids" routerLink='/bids/5edbd6eb3290c300179cc2f9'>{{data.totalBids}} BIDS RECEIVED</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to use query params but you have not and that's why your routing isnt working.
Since ```routerLink="/projectdetail/{{data._id}}"``` is dynamic, your route has to be defined for every possible value of ```data.id``` otherwise it wont route.
So what you can do is 
```routerLink="/projectdetail" [queryParams]="{id: data.id}"``` to your div.

Resultant url: ```projectdetails?id=someid```

Comment: Did you try : `[routerLink]="['/projectdetail/',data._id]"`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is a good practice to have nested RouterLinks, but this solution might work in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147466/12660773

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the router link on the `bids` `div` and replacing it with `(click)=nav()` and then in your `.ts` file:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

nav() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/bids/5edbd6eb3290c300179cc2f9');
}
```